# Unable to connect kafka Consumer to Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have Kafka cluster with 3 broker nodes. When all are up and running, consumer able to read data from Kafka. However if I stop all Kafka server and brings up only 2 Kafka server except the one which stopped last then Consumer unable to connect to Kafka cluster.
What could be the reason behind this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Consumer unable to connect to Kafka cluster" - what error do you get?

Comment: [2020-11-27 17:51:29,802] [Consumer clientId=EVENT_CLIENT, groupId=3] Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-11-27 17:51:29,802] [Consumer clientId=EVENT_CLIENT, groupId=3] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem could be the offsets.topic.replication.factor in the broker that by default is 3 while you are now running a cluster with 2 brokers only.
This is the topic where the consumers store the offsets when consuming and it was created with replication factor of 3 on the first run.
When, on the second run, you start only 2 broker, it could be the problem now.

Comment: But Its work fine if all are running and if I stop one. This problem occurs only when If I stop all three and start only 2 which are stopped first (The one which stopped last is still down)